# Falstads circuit simulator : capacitors have initial voltage?

Tags: capacitor, falstad

I started playing with Paul Falstad's circuit simulator applet to see if it would be useful for my intro physics students. However, I'm running into a quirk regarding capacitors which I don't really understand. Namely it appears that capacitors start with a voltage difference of 1 mV, with the positive terminal being whichever endpoint was chosen first. Is there an obvious way to eliminate this behavior? I would much prefer that capacitors start with no initial voltage, i.e., uncharged. (I can 'hack' a solution as such: create two capacitors of capacitance *2C* and connect their positive terminals. This creates an effective capacitance of *C* and ensures no voltage difference across the two negative terminals. But such a procedure seems tedious to do repeatedly.)

**[(Link to example circuit)](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+43%0Ac+-80+272+-80+160+0+0.00001+0.001%0Ap+48+160+48+272+1+0%0Aw+-80+272+48+272+0%0Aw+48+160+-80+160+0%0Ag+-80+272+-80+304+0%0Ao+1+64+0+4098+0.001220703125+0.1+0+1%0A)**

[image: Falstad capacitor initial voltage]

Comment: @jsotola - It appears they do. I just added a link to an example circuit in the question

Comment: @jsotola One aspect I carelessly omitted is that it's strangely dependent on the order of steps. If you delete the capacitor in Bort's example and replace it with a new one from the Draw menu, then the voltage probe indeed shows 0V. But if you now hit the reset button, then the voltage jumps to 1 mV.

Comment: confirmed the behavior ... i wonder if it is a kludge of some kind

Comment: falstad has an offline version link at the bottom of this page ... http://www.falstad.com/circuit/ ..... just look for 0.001 in the files ... my internet connection is failing me today, so i cannot download and test

Comment: managed to download offline version ... found a couple of files with a 0.001 ... changed the value ... calacitor still initializes to 1 mV ... perhaps you may want to contact Falstad

Comment: turns out that the app has a source repository  ... https://github.com/sharpie7/circuitjs1

Answer (score 4):

In the current version of the simulator, if you right-click a capacitor and click "Edit..." then a window appears in which you can choose what the capacitor's initial voltage is. For some reason, the default value is 1 mV, but you can change it to 0.

[image: A screenshot of Paul Falstad's circuit simulator at falstad.com/circuit. There is a capacitor, and next to it is the "Edit Component" window, with the "Initial Voltage (on Reset)" property set to 1 millivolt.]

Comment: My guess is that this is to facilitate building circuits that in the real world rely on a small amount of noise or residual voltage to start.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer, but a possible workaround.

Falstad uses the URL to hold the circuit definition.

It contains the starting voltage of the capacitor.

[This URL starts the capacitor at 1 mV.](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2043%0Ac%20-80%20272%20-80%20160%200%200.00001%200.001%0Ap%2048%20160%2048%20272%201%200%0Aw%20-80%20272%2048%20272%200%0Aw%2048%20160%20-80%20160%200%0Ag%20-80%20272%20-80%20304%200%0Ao%201%2064%200%204098%200.001220703125%200.1%200%201%0A)

```
https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+43%0Ac+-80+272+-80+160+0+0.00001+0.001%0Ap+48+160+48+272+1+0%0Aw+-80+272+48+272+0%0Aw+48+160+-80+160+0%0Ag+-80+272+-80+304+0%0Ao+1+64+0+4098+0.001220703125+0.1+0+1%0A
```

.
.

[This URL starts the capacitor at 0 V.](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2043%0Ac%20-80%20272%20-80%20160%200%200.00001%200.0%0Ap%2048%20160%2048%20272%201%200%0Aw%20-80%20272%2048%20272%200%0Aw%2048%20160%20-80%20160%200%0Ag%20-80%20272%20-80%20304%200%0Ao%201%2064%200%204098%200.001220703125%200.1%200%201%0A)

```
https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+43%0Ac+-80+272+-80+160+0+0.00001+0.0%0Ap+48+160+48+272+1+0%0Aw+-80+272+48+272+0%0Aw+48+160+-80+160+0%0Ag+-80+272+-80+304+0%0Ao+1+64+0+4098+0.001220703125+0.1+0+1%0A
```

This is how the URL breaks down.

```
https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html

?cct=$

+1
+0.000005
+10.20027730826997
+50
+5
+43
%0A

c                   capacitor
+-80
+272
+-80
+160
+0
+0.00001
+0.001              starting voltage
%0A

p
+48
+160
+48
+272
+1
+0
%0A

w
+-80
+272
+48
+272
+0
%0A

w
+48
+160
+-80
+160
+0
%0A

g
+-80
+272
+-80
+304
+0
%0A

o
+1
+64
+0
+4098
+0.001220703125
+0.1
+0
+1
%0A
```

.
.
addendum:

Searched through the source code at https://github.com/sharpie7/circuitjs1

Found this in `CapacitorElm.java`.

```
void reset() {
    super.reset();
    current = curcount = curSourceValue = 0;
    // put small charge on caps when reset to start oscillators
    voltdiff = 1e-3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This at least makes clear where the issue was coming from. It's strange, though, that this property isn't documented anywhere and (as far as I can tell) can't be adjusted within the simulator itself. (There's also the question of -why- the posted simulator assumes an initial capacitor voltage, but I guess that's a question for Falstad himself...)

Comment: This does appear to work, here's the link to the example circuit with the cap initial voltage manually edited: https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+43%0Ac+-80+272+-80+160+0+0.00001+0.000%0Ap+48+160+48+272+1+0%0Aw+-80+272+48+272+0%0Aw+48+160+-80+160+0%0Ag+-80+272+-80+304+0%0Ao+1+64+0+4098+0.001220703125+0.1+0+1%0A

Comment: One limitation of this fix: If you edit the URL but subsequently hit the 'reset' button, then the circuit resets to the 1mv default regardless of the edited URL.

Comment: @Semiclassical, updated answer with more info